# Create nohup.out file based on date

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, nohup

I am using `nohup` command to run a java web server application. This is the command i am using:

```
nohup java -jar WEB-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

This command will create a `nohup.out` and my server logs are stored in this file. I want this file creation based on date i.e if current date is **2017-10-28**, file should be created `nohup.2017-10-28.out` and when the date becomes **2017-10-29 12:00 AM** `nohup.2017-10-29.out` file should be automatically created and so on . Example:

```
DATE       | File 
           |
2017-10-28 | nohup.2017-10-28.out
2017-10-29 | nohup.2017-10-29.out
2017-10-30 | nohup.2017-10-30.out
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just redirect the output to a file.

```
nohup java -jar WEB-SNAPSHOT.jar > nohup.$(date --iso).out
```

If you redirect, `nohup` will not create the default file, but will use the file specified with the redirect.
I also think you do not need the `&` at the end of your command.

Comment: Consider current date is `2017-10-28 ` at 2017-10-29 12:00 AM does this command create nohup.2017-10-29.out file

Comment: Nope, `nohup` redirects to the file specified. It does not alter the output file. If you want to have a new filename you would have to stop the current instance and reexeute the command or use `logrotate` or similar.

Comment: Could you please answer with `logrotate` bcoz i am unable to find any useful result from google search

Comment: & is needed if you want the application to continue running even after the current terminal session closes.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to background a process and log its stdout to a file, there are more features available if you implement it as a service.

Create a [systemd service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) that starts a command similar to  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/app/WEB-SNAPSHOT.tar`

Also set it to log to a unique syslog destination as described in [systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

```
StandardOutput=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=app
SyslogFacility=local6
```

Set syslog to log that facility to its own file like  `/var/log/app.log`

Configure /etc/logrotate.d/app to rotate the file. Use dateformat and postrotate scripts as necessary.

```
/var/log/app.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am facing difficulty in understanding your answer as I am not a expert in linux. Could you provide me more information

Comment: systemd manages many things including services. If you were to write a .service unit, you can start, stop, and manage the logging of a process.  To learn more, read documentation like the RHEL guide to Creating and Modifying systemd Unit Files.